# Why nextImg and prevImg can't set elements's src attribution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
 
                                          
var imgs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mucrb.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BH67.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdNeR.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/StOAl.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhvqi.png"];    
bs = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i =0;i<bs.length;i++){
    bs[i].addEventListener("click",showImg);
}
pLeft =document.getElementById("left");
pLeft.addEventListener("click",prevImg);
pRight =document.getElementById("right");
pRight.addEventListener("click",nextImg);

function showImg(e){
    x = e.target.getAttribute("order");
    document.getElementById("loopImg").setAttribute("src",imgs[x-1]);
}  

function  nextImg(e){
    x = e.target.getAttribute("order");
    if(x == imgs.length-1){
        x = 0;}
    else{
        x = x+1;}
    document.getElementById("loopImg").setAttribute("src",imgs[x]);
}

function prevImg(e){
    x = e.target.getAttribute("order");
    if(x == 0){
        x = imgs.length-1;}
    else{
        x = x-1;}
    document.getElementById("loopImg").setAttribute("src",imgs[x]);
}
```

```css
#main{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:60px auto 60px;
    grid-template-rows:60px auto 60px;
    grid-template-areas:"des des des"
                         "left  loopImg  right"
                        "buttons buttons buttons";
    margin:0 auto;
}

#des{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row:1/2;
    margin:auto;
}

#loopImg{
    grid-column:2/3;
    grid-row:2/3;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:auto;
}

#left{
    grid-column:1/2;
    grid-row:2/3;
    margin:auto;
}
#right{
    grid-column:3/4;
    grid-row:2/3;
    margin:auto;
}

#buttons{
    grid-column:1/4;
    grid-row:3/4;
    margin:auto;
}

button{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid green;
    border-radius:50%;
}

img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="des">loop images</div>
    <img id="loopImg" src="i1.png" alt="">
    <p id="left">&lt;</p>
    <p id="right">&gt;</p>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button order="1" >1</button>
        <button order="2" >2</button>
        <button order="3" >3</button>
        <button order="4" >4</button>
        <button order="5" >5</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to write a loop images js script.
To click the button ,image can display according to the number in button.
Why  nextImg and prevImg can't set elements's src attribution when to click them?
The nextImg can only work for one click, it can't run when to click for the second time.
The prevImg can't work at all.
It can get the order number when to click button key, how to get the order number when to click pLeft and pRight key?
The statement `x = e.target.getAttribute("order");` in nextImg and prevImg can't get image's order number,how to fix it?

Comment: What you need to do is store the index of the currently displayed image somewhere and work with that; getAttribute("order") is always the same value.

Comment: **Strongly** recommend adopting one of the standard bracing (`{}`), schemes, not the one used above. Editing that code is a **lot** harder than it should be.

Comment: You're also using <button> elements; be aware that when you ever add a <form> around this code, that the buttons will submit the form and reload the page when you click one.

Comment: replace < and > with `&lt;`  and `&gt;`.

Comment: u try to get order attribute of the left/right buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevImg` and `nextImg` don't work because:

1. Those elements don't have an `order` attribute, so you get `null` from `e.target.getAttribute("order")`, and
2. In the case of `nextImg`, if it *did* have the attribute, its value would be a string, so `x = x + 1` would be *string concatenation*, not addition.

Instead, maintain the current index in a variable, see `***` comments:

```js
var imgs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mucrb.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BH67.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdNeR.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/StOAl.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhvqi.png"];    
var bs = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); // *** Added var
for(var i =0;i<bs.length;i++){
    bs[i].addEventListener("click",showImg);
}
var pLeft =document.getElementById("left");   // *** Added var
pLeft.addEventListener("click",prevImg);
var pRight =document.getElementById("right"); // *** Added var
pRight.addEventListener("click",nextImg);

var currentIndex = 0; // ***
// *** Reusable function so we aren't repeating ourselves constantly below
function displayImage(src) {
    // *** Notice the .src property
    document.getElementById("loopImg").src = src;
}
displayImage(imgs[0]); // *** Show the first image

function showImg(e){
    // *** Note the unary + to convert to number
    currentIndex = +e.target.getAttribute("order") - 1;
    displayImage(imgs[currentIndex]);
}  

function  nextImg(e){
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgs.length; // *** Wraps around
    displayImage(imgs[currentIndex]);
}

function prevImg(e){
    currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + imgs.length) % imgs.length; // *** Wraps around
    displayImage(imgs[currentIndex]);
}
```

```css
#main{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:60px auto 60px;
    grid-template-rows:60px auto 60px;
    grid-template-areas:"des des des"
                         "left  loopImg  right"
                        "buttons buttons buttons";
    margin:0 auto;
}

#des{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row:1/2;
    margin:auto;
}

#loopImg{
    grid-column:2/3;
    grid-row:2/3;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:auto;
}

#left{
    grid-column:1/2;
    grid-row:2/3;
    margin:auto;
}
#right{
    grid-column:3/4;
    grid-row:2/3;
    margin:auto;
}

#buttons{
    grid-column:1/4;
    grid-row:3/4;
    margin:auto;
}

button{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid green;
    border-radius:50%;
}

img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="des">loop images</div>
    <img id="loopImg" src="" alt="">
    <p id="left">&lt;<!-- *** Note using entity for '<' --></p>
    <p id="right">></p>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button order="1" >1</button>
        <button order="2" >2</button>
        <button order="3" >3</button>
        <button order="4" >4</button>
        <button order="5" >5</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: I didn't do a full audit of the code or anything like that. I did notice that in multiple places, the original code was falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Be sure to declare your variables (`bs`, `x`, `pLeft`, `pRight`), in the narrowest scope you can.

Answer (score 2):

On the click of left and right, you are trying to get the arribute `order` of the clicked element. But actually it doesn't have any attribute like that..
What I have done is added a counter as to where is the current selected image. so whenever you click left or right, I decrement/increment the counter and set the image attribute with the waht the counter index says..

```js
var imgs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mucrb.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BH67.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdNeR.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/StOAl.png",
             "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhvqi.png"];    
bs = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i =0;i<bs.length;i++){
    bs[i].addEventListener("click",showImg);
}
pLeft =document.getElementById("left");
pLeft.addEventListener("click",prevImg);
pRight =document.getElementById("right");
pRight.addEventListener("click",nextImg);

function showImg(e){
    x = e.target.getAttribute("order");
    document.getElementById("loopImg").setAttribute("src",imgs[x-1]);
    currentImage = x-1
}  

var currentImage = 0;

function  nextImg(){
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % 5
    document.getElementById("loopImg").setAttribute("src",imgs[currentImage]);
}

function prevImg(){
   
    if (currentImage === 0) {
      currentImage = 4
    }
    else {
      currentImage --;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("loopImg").setAttribute("src",imgs[currentImage]);
}
```

```css
#main{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:60px auto 60px;
    grid-template-rows:60px auto 60px;
    grid-template-areas:"des des des"
                         "left  loopImg  right"
                        "buttons buttons buttons";
    margin:0 auto;
}

#des{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row:1/2;
    margin:auto;
}

#loopImg{
    grid-column:2/3;
    grid-row:2/3;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:auto;
}

#left{
    grid-column:1/2;
    grid-row:2/3;
    margin:auto;
}
#right{
    grid-column:3/4;
    grid-row:2/3;
    margin:auto;
}

#buttons{
    grid-column:1/4;
    grid-row:3/4;
    margin:auto;
}

button{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid green;
    border-radius:50%;
}

img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="des">loop images</div>
    <img id="loopImg" src="i1.png" alt="">
    <p id="left"><</p>
    <p id="right">></p>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button order="1" >1</button>
        <button order="2" >2</button>
        <button order="3" >3</button>
        <button order="4" >4</button>
        <button order="5" >5</button>
    </div>
</div>
```